# Как изменить содержимое txt фала с помощью js?

Tags: javascript

Я создал приложение с использованием html и js наподобие приложения из этого  [видео](https://youtu.be/4zrZh949wbg?si=L25goj6eAZ_3aRg0) .

Я хочу, чтобы в нём пользователь выбрал цвет на задний фон, поставил его и смог сохранить его в файле `color.txt`, предварительно созданном мною в папке www.

А при следующем запуске js "достал" содержимое этого файла и поставил его на цвет фона. Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. К сожалению, local Storage не работает.

```js
function changeBC() {
  let color = document.getElementById("inputColor").value;
  let body = document.getElementById("body");
  body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  
  <input type="color" id="inputColor">
  <button onclick="changeBC()" id="userColor">поставить цвет</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Почему localStorage не работает? Для того, что бы менять на сервере файл, вам придется написать АПИ на бэке, который будет обрабатывать запросы от пользователя на изменение. Так же надо отправлять пользователю его настройки.

Comment: Опишите, что у вас не работает. Непонятно из вопроса. Есть ли ошибки. Приложите их, если они есть.

Comment: Мне просто хочется, чтобы цвет, который пользователь ввёл в input type color, сохранился в файле color.txt, а при следующем запуске приложения js ставил этот цвет как background-color. А ошибок никаких нет. Internal Storage я не включил в код, т.к. он не действует, просто не сохраняет данные.

Comment: Судя по вашему стилю кода и еще вот по этому `document.getElementById("userColor").value` - то код у вас в целом не рабочий. Вы пытаетесь взять значение кнопки... подозреваю, что и localStorage вы прикрутили не так и нитуда. Вашу задумку на клиенте можно сделать через localStorage. Через сохранение в файл нет.

Comment: Отправляйте ajax запрос и сохраняйте/читайте цвет. localStorage хранит данные в локальном хранилище браузера (на клиенте) и к файлам на сервере никакого отношения/доступа не имеет.

Comment: А кто сказал, что `JS` способен записывать в **TXT**  что-то?

Comment: @Air, в зависимости от того где и как запускается js - способен

Comment: @Grundy, судя по сему, автор хочет это все в браузере реализовать, так что мой коммент не лишен истины... И я тоже рад тебя видеть...))

Answer (score 0):

`JS` не работает с `txt` файлами, это браузерный (в большинстве случаев) язык програмирования. Вы пишите свои мечты не разобравшись в технологии.

То о чем вы описали "возможно" реализовать на серверном языче прогрммирования `php, NodeJS ...` но лучше так не делать, и решить браузерным подходом.
Даже с точки зрения безопасности, кто-то может подменить содержание `txt` и вы получите много проблем.

Comment: Да что вы говорите...

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: в браузерном js можно работать с файлами, используя блобы и fileReader ы.

Comment: @Exord А Вас не смущает, тот большой красный прямоугольник ? "FileReader используется только для безопасным образом чтения содержимого файла из пользовательской (удалённой) системы."  где тут про "сохранить его в файле color.txt"  .... Работать и "уметь читать" несколько разные весщи, не находите ?

Comment: @Exord не позорься, умник. Считать файл к которому пользователь дал доступ (или с помощью запроса на удаленный адрес) это одно дело, а в вопросе речь о ЗАПИСИ и чтении txt, который ожидается на сервере... Это совершенно разные вещи. Вы так, похожие слова увидели в вопросе и в статье, но не понимаете о чем вообще говорите

Comment: @Gelloiss Ладно ладно ребят, полегче) Мои комментарии, лишь к ответу блекстара (О том что js не работает с txt файлами). Но напрямую - конечно js не может писать в файлы удалённого сервера, нужна прослойка какого-либо бэкенда.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 На самом деле это не совсем так, ибо FileReader может прочитать blob объект. А блоб можно сформировать получив его с бекенда. Это может быть полезно, если нужен единый интерфейс взаимодействия и с клиентскими файлами, и с удалёнными.

Comment: @Gelloiss но я соглашаюсь с тем, что к вопросу это имеет мало отношения.